# How to get all nodes within an area surrounded by a node type by using Cypher (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to do the following:

- Let's say this is the initial graph: [Initial Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAhY9.png)

I want to get all the blue nodes between red nodes and connect them to a new yellow node. I want to do this for every blue node area seperated by red nodes.

- What I am trying to tell: [The Result I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYhxw.png)

I want to do this without creating redundant yellow nodes and unnecessary traversals. Also, I want to do this in a single query, if it is possible.

---

Initially I achieved creating yellow nodes and connecting them by getting paths which start with a red node and end with another red node. However, this solution led to creating redundant yellow nodes since there are some areas seperated by 3 or more red nodes. For instance if a blue node area is seperated by 3 red nodes, this solution finds 3 different paths in that area, therefore creates 3 different yellow nodes. So I had to delete redundant yellow nodes in another query which was terrible in terms of efficiency.

After that, I tried using apoc expand functions, however they require minLevel and maxLevel parameters which again leads to finding more than one path in a blue node area.

In short, the real question is how can I achieve getting each blue node area as a single path without compromising efficiency?

**Edit:** I also tried creating a yellow node for each blue node directly connected to the red node near it and then connected the other blue nodes to the yellow node if they are reachable through blue nodes, however this query also takes too much time.

As far as I am concerned matching paths like the following query affects time efficiency too negatively:

```
MATCH path = (:YELLOW)-[link*]-(:BLUE)-[:CONNECTION]-(:RED)
WHERE single(x IN nodes(path) WHERE x:RED)
//Then connect nodes in path to the yellow node if there is no connection
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Some of the results are not a single path, so it is practically impossible

Comment: If so, how can I get blue nodes?

Comment: MATCH (startnode:RED)-[link*]->(blue)
WITH collect(distinct(id(blue))) as blueIds
WITH distict blueIds as distinctBlueSets // make sure you only have unique sets of nodes

Maybe you have to sort the by internal id (or some id property) before you collect
...